# fetch api - how to append an array as a search param

Tags: javascript, url, fetch-api

I'm trying to find out if there is a proper way to append an array to a url search-param using the native [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) APIs. For example - if I would like to append an array of one or more items to a `list` parameter.
For the moment I found this solution which works fine:

```js
async function fetchList(array){
 const url = new URL('http://localhost:8080/some-route');
 
 array.forEach(item => url.searchParams.append('list[]', item)); 

 const res = await fetch(url);
 return res.json();
}

fetchList(['item1','item2', 'item3'])
```

However, I was wondering if there is any native abstraction which might spare me iterating over the array and appending each of its items to `'list[]'` (which feels a bit hacky..)

Comment: I don't think there is. jQuery can simplify this, but I don't think there's any native JS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to do a bulk add to an URLSearchParams. Either it needs to be a loop using [`URLSearchParams#append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) as demonstrated in the question:

```js
const array = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

const url = new URL('http://localhost:8080/some-route');
array.forEach(item => url.searchParams.append('list[]', item));

console.log(url);
```

Or an alternative might be to generate a new `URLSearchParams` object since the [constructor takes any iterable which produces key-value pairs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams):

```js
const array = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

const url = new URL('http://localhost:8080/some-route');

const newSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(array.map(x => ["list[]", x]));
url.search = newSearchParams;

console.log(url);
```

The new object needs to be assigned to the [`URL#search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/search) because [`URL#searchParams` is readonly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams).

Technically `search` should be a string and [`URLSearchParameters#toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString) is overloaded to provide a compatible search string. Thus `url.search = newSearchParams.toString()` would be more formally correct, however `toString()` is used by the implicit conversion anyway, so assigning the object still has the same result.